# Complex number arithmetic in Tcl?

Tags: parsing, expression, tcl, complex-numbers

Is there an equivalent to the `expr` command which works for complex numbers (represented lists of two doubles)?

[This](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/qcomplex.html) library provides functions for complex number arithmetic, and [this](http://wiki.tcl.tk/15703) seems to be a useful utility to define the required `cexpr` function, but it doesn't work well.

E.g. it doesn't handle properly the brackets.

```
ParseExpressions::ParseExpr { (1) + ((2) + (3)) } { }
```

returns

```
+ [+ 1 ((2)] (3))
```

while it should return

```
+ [+ 1 2] 3
```

Also
ParseExpressions::ParseExpr { {1 2} + {3 4} } {}

returns

```
+ 1 2 3 4
```

while it should return

```
+ {1 2} {3 4}
```

So basically I am asking for a robust version of [this](http://wiki.tcl.tk/15703) utility.

Comment: This is a good question; it will take time to get an acceptable solution.

Comment: Suggest reading: http://wiki.tcl.tk/1612 (about complex math implemented in TCL)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you try this: http://wiki.tcl.tk/11415
or something like this too: http://wiki.tcl.tk/13885

I hope these are easy to use alternatives for the mentioned utility.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pretty much an C library if you link it with FFIDL.